# Do the laws of Negiah depend on sexual orientation?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, sexuality, negia, yichud-seclusion

The Rambam writes ([Hilchos Isurei Biah 21:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5121.htm)):

> כל הבא על ערווה מן העריות דרך אברים, או שחיבק ונישק דרך תאווה ונהנה בקירוב בשר--הרי זה לוקה מן התורה
>
> One who comes upon one of the *Arayos* via their limbs, or hugs or kisses in a **lustful manner** and benefits from the touching of skin receives *malkus* according to the Torah.

The implication is that the category of Shomer Negiah is only applicable with regards to lustful touching. Now I am aware that there is a discussion of cases where lustful pleasure is highly unlikely, e.g. shaking hands in a business setting. However, it seems to be the common practice that men and women will casually touch members of the same sex, since it is assumed that they cannot be attracted to each other at all. What about the case where one or both of the parties has a [homosexual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality), [bisexual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisexuality), or [asexual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asexuality) orientation?  How will this change the categories of people that may be touched?

For clarity, here are two examples to illustrate this question:

- May an asexual man touch a woman? (Normally we assume that the man could be attracted to the woman, but in this case we know that he is not.)
- May a bisexual man touch a man? (Normally we assume that the man could not be attracted to the other man, but in this case we know that he could be, potentially.)

I am also interested hearing about how yichud might or might not apply in such cases, if it is relevant.

Comment: related:  
 שו"ע אבן העזר - סימן כד 
 סימן כד - אין ישראל חשודים על הרביעה ועל הזכר:
(א) לא נחשדו ישראל על משכב זכר ועל הבהמה, לפיכך אין איסור להתייחד עמהן, ואם נתרחק אפילו מיחוד זכר ובהמה, הרי זה משובח. וגדולי החכמים היו מרחיקין הבהמה, כדי שלא יתייחדו עמה. ובדורות הללו שרבו הפריצים, יש להתרחק מלהתייחד עם הזכר:

Comment: @avi That's the opposite, though.

Comment: @DoubleAA how is that the opposite?

Comment: @avi It's saying two people who we wouldn't expect to have certain attractions, but do, regain the prohibition. Doesn't discuss people who don't have the attractions we expect them to have (that's what I thought the question was about, anyway).

Comment: @doubleaa yichud is not negiah,  but how is it opposite. If a man makes it public that they are homosexual they can't be in a room alone with another man.

Comment: @avi I think DoubleAA means that if a man is homosexual, we can ask if he should be able to be misyached/touch a woman even though normally a man couldn't.

Comment: Let me clarify: I'm interested BOTH in people who have an attraction we don't expect, and people who don't have an attraction we do expect. I'll try to make that clearer in the question.

Comment: You seem to be reading a lot into the "דרך תאווה" here.  If it worked as you seem to suggest, there would be no problem with me kissing my grandmother's friends on the cheek as a greeting.  It may be affectionate, but there is surely no lust there.

Answer (score 4):

This question is tricky because it's not clear that Halachah recognizes such a  phenomenon of one who is just asexual though technically physically capable of sexual intercourse. 
Similarly, it's not clear whether Halachah recognizes absolute homosexual orientation as one who not only is irrevocably attracted to men but also absolutely uninterested in women, despite the fact that he, too, is physically capable of sexual intercourse with a woman. 
However, whether homosexuality itself leads to its own requirements of forbidding Yichud with other males is already addressed. See Tur and SA EH [24](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.24.1?lang=bi&with=Tur) and [Bach](https://www.sefaria.org/Bach%2C_Even_HaEzer.24), [ChM](https://www.sefaria.org/Chelkat_Mechokek.24), and [BSh](https://www.sefaria.org/Beit_Shmuel.24) there, as well as Chochmas Adam [126:14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14718&st=&pgnum=338); Aruch HaShulchan EH [24:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Even_HaEzer.24.6); Shu"T Daas Kohen (Kuk) [YD 3](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20315&pgnum=16). If one knows himself to have homosexual tendencies then indeed he must not be alone with another male, especially if the other male also has such tendencies.
Regarding an asexual or homosexual man being alone with a woman, it would appear that indeed since he is physically capable of sexual intercourse all Halachos of Yichud would apply. All literature on the issue discuss whether or not one who is physically incapable of sexual intercourse may be lenient regarding Yichud- and even then it's not simple...

Comment: This answer could be improved if you'd include citations for the "asexual or homosexual man being alone with a woman" side of the question. Though you may not have literature that directly addresses that question, you've alluded to literature that comes close.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thank you very much for the answers. Consider checking out the following short Beginners' Guide: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775.

Comment: שו"ת זית רענן א א"ה א; שו"ת דברי מלכיאל ד קב; שו"ת מאורות נתן מז; דבר הלכה, בהוספות לסי' ב, בשם החזו"א; הגרש"ז אויערבאך, הו"ד בנשמת אברהם א"ה כב,ב; ההלכה במשפחה טו,יד; שו"ת ציץ אליעזר ז,מה,ב- דעת הגרי"ש אלישיב; שם ו,מ- כב,ח; שם ז,מו; שם ח,יד,ז; שם יב,סז,ב-ה; שו"ת אגרות משה א"ה (ד) סה,י; דבר הלכה ב,ט... כולם מבואר שכל הקולא האפשרי הוא דוקא מפני היותו בלתי יכול להתקשות פיזית כלל... עיין בדברי כולם היטב.

Comment: ומה גם שהייתי מתכבד לקבל מקורות מספרות ההלכתית הקלאסית לכך שמוכרת ומתקבלת נטייה מינית שהיא או הומוסקסואלית אקסקלוסיבית או שהוא לגמרי "א-סקסואל" עכ"כ שבלתי מסוגל להתקשות כלל כאילו ניטל ממנו "כח-גברא" באופן פיזי...